# How to upload image with form body and iformfile in net core web api, and copy it to server folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, iformfile

I want to upload image to web api and submit data in one time, but it return me 415 code error

i have try to change it to fromForm but it not working to

```
[HttpPost("Vendor")]
 public IActionResult NewAdds([FromBody] Ads add, IFormFile file)
 {
   //copy file first then insert
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {}
}
```

it returns 415. Here result on postman

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "80000041-0003-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}
```

Comment: hi , I have the same issue. Have you figured it out?

Answer (score 1):

For those looking at this, you'll want to add the `IForm file` as a field within the `Ads` object. Than rather than using `[FromBody]`, you'll want to use the `[FromForm]` option.

Comment: this works as described. You should probably add an example to your answer for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a form with an input Type of File

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="" asp-action="Upload">
  <input type="file" name="files" accept="image/*" id='' multiple />
</form>
```

Make your action accept Files

```
public IActionResult Upload(List<IFormFile> files)
```

Writing the file to a server folder should be considerably easy provided you have all the necessary access